# An Interesting Number Theory Problem: Solve $2520=(x+y+xy)^2+2xy+2y-3x, x, y \in \mathbb Z$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, quadratics

Solve:

> $2520=(x+y+xy)^2+2xy+2y-3x$

Please help, I tried Solving SFFT and Quadratic, but couldn't end up with a result.

Edit: I solved this much.I factorized it
$((x+1)(y+1)-1)^2+2((x+1)(y+1)-1)-5x$
Then substituted $t=((x+1)(y+1)-1)$
so $t^2+2t-5x=2520$
and after this i am stuck
Edit 2: Solve for Integers

Comment: Show what you tried, we help you to end it.

Comment: Requesting you to help me i have showed please help

Comment: Presumably $x,y$ are integers? If so, please add it into your question. (The problem might be different if they need to be positive integers vs just integers, for example, which is why it makes a difference.)

Comment: integers please but ,requesting you to guide me till the end of the solution

Comment: Now solve the equation you found. The discriminant $\Delta$ will be a function of x, try to see for which x it is perfect square. then check it in equation.

Comment: i am not good in that and i tried doing it and could not get a solution , requesting you to show me complete steps,my dear friend

Comment: One idea: $|x|, |y|$ cannot be too big as the first term would dominate the others. Try find an upper bound and check the smaller cases one by one.

Comment: Requesting you to write me a complete solution please ,My dear Friend

Comment: If $x$ and $y$ be are integer, so you can see that $(x,y)=(16,-4)$ and $(x,y)=(16,2)$ be are solution of your problem.

Comment: Please write me a complete solution With Steps My Dear Friend

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$2520=x^2+y^2+(xy)^2+2x^2y+2y^2x+2xy+2xy+2y-3x$$ so, if we group in terms of $y$ $$2520=y^2(x^2+2x+1)+y(2x^2+4x+2)+x^2-3x$$ so $$0=y^2\cdot(x+1)^2+2y(x+1)^2+x^2-3x-2520$$ so solving the quadratic equation in the usual way:

$$\Delta=4(x+1)^4-4(x+1)^2(x^2-3x)=4(x+1)^2(x^2+2x+1-x^2+3x+2520)$$ so we have found out that $$\Delta=(2x+2)^2\cdot(5x+2521)$$

but we know

$$y=\frac{-2(x+1)^2\pm\sqrt{\Delta}}{2(x+1)^2}=\pm\frac{\sqrt{\Delta}}{2(x+1)^2}-1=\pm\frac{2(x+1)\sqrt{5x+2521}}{2(x+1)^2}-1=\pm\frac{\sqrt{5x+2521}}{(x+1)}-1$$ so for $y$ to be an integer, $x+1$ must divide $\sqrt{5x+2521}$ and  $5x+2521$ must be a perfect square. Let $5x+2521=k^2$ so $x=\frac{k^2-2521}{5}$ so $$\big(\frac{k^2-2521}{5}+1\big)^2\text{ divides } k$$ so $$(k^2-2516)^2\text{ divides } 25k$$ so $$(k^2-2516)^2\leq 25|k|$$ which gives us $k=\pm50,\pm51$. If $k=\pm 50$, then because $x=\frac{k^2-2521}{5}$, x wouldn't be an integer so contradiction. So $k=51$, so $x=\frac{51^2-2521}{5}=16$

Because $x=16$ wecan now see that because $y=\pm\frac{\sqrt{5x+2521}}{(x+1)}-1=\pm3-1$ so $y$ is $2$ or $-4$.

So the solutions are $(x,y)=(16,-4)$ and $(16,2)$

Comment: Here it is, @siddhartha bhattacharya. I rewrote it and now it si all clear

Comment: thank you very much,respect

Comment: i guess there is a slight calculation mistake at the end

Comment: y would be equal to -4 ,2 ,instead of plus minus 3 -1 you wrote +-3+1

Comment: Yes i will edit it in. It is $\pm3-1$

Comment: @Vlad just wondering, how did you get the solutions $k = \pm 50, \pm 51$ from the inequality $(k^2 - 2516)^2 \leq 25|k|$?

Comment: As a remark, note that $2520=50^2+20$ so we can do $x+y+xy=50$ and$xy+2y-3x=20$ so easily we obtain $5x=80$. The other solution comes from $52^2-184=2520$.

Answer (score 3):

Denote $z=x+1, w=y+1$ then your result $$t^2+2t-5x=2520 \implies (t+1)^2-5(z-1)=2519 \\\implies w^2z^2-5z=2516=z(w^2 z - 5) \implies z|2516=2^2\cdot 17\cdot 37$$

If $z$ is even then $w^2z-5$ is odd, so $4|z, z=4u, 4u^2w^2=5u+629 \implies u\equiv -1 \pmod 4$, and $u|17\cdot 37$, therefore $u=-1, -17, -37, -629$, none of which yields a perfect square for $5u+629$.

If $z$ is odd then $wz$ is odd, $(wz)^2 \equiv 1 \pmod 4$, so $z\equiv 1 \pmod 4, z=1, 17, 37, 629$. We have the following four cases:

$z=1, w^2-5=2516$, no solution;

$z=17, 17w^2-5=148 \implies w=\pm 3 \implies x=16, y=2 \text{ or } -4;$

$z=37, 37w^2-5=68$, no solution;

$z=629, 629w^2-5=4$, no solution.

So the only solutions are $(16, 2)$ and $(16, -4)$.

Comment: i'm thankful to you

Comment: just 1 correction w=t+1, you by mistake wrote w=y+1

Comment: No $w=y+1$. I used your notation $t=(x+1)(y+1)-1$.

Comment: o,ok thanks ,couldnt realize it